# Use both manual switch and WiFi smart switches together

Tags: switches, lamp, wifi-direct

I have a Sonoff Basic WiFi Smart Switch that I would like to connect to my lamp and control via my phone.

However, if something will go wrong, or there would not be WiFi or for whatever other reason, I want to have the possibility to switch the lamp on/off manually also.

The manual switch is the simplest one, where you can just on and off it; 2 wires are coming to that switch. In the WiFi switch, 2 wires are coming in and 2 are coming out (N, L).

Comment: Not many of us are going to be familiar with this device. Can you add a link to the datasheet?

Comment: If you can program the power on reset state to "ON", you can just wire an inline switch before the wifi switch. Manual control would work as expected. With the physical switch off, there is nothing the smart switch can do about.

Answer (score 1):

The Wifi switch you mention is not meant to work with a switch. With only an L and N terminal it will connect or break the line to turn on the light. If you install a switch, the switch will turn the light off if it's on but it will kill power to the Wifi switch as well. You would have to turn the switch back on to use the Wifi. Also if you wanted to turn the light on the switch would not be able to do that.

To do what you want, you need a 3way or 4way Wifi switch.